# Possibility of merging Windows 10 Lockscreen questions

Tags: discussion

@[Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) gave this rule of thumb on [SOmeta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262499/1505120):

> Merging should only happen when the answers to one question are a perfect match to another. If there's information missing from one set of answers, it's probably not a good merge candidate.

Given the likes of:

Q: [Windows 10 Wallpaper - photo location](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65747/windows-10-wallpaper-photo-location)

I've upgraded my laptop to Win10, and I have this wallpaper on my screen: I like this place and I wanted to know - where it exactly is? Search in Internet gave me this old post about windows wallpapers and similar question on Microsoft site with no answer. …

Q: [What is the location of this Windows 10 wallpaper?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74416/what-is-the-location-of-this-windows-10-wallpaper)

Saw this from Windows 10 wallpaper. Hope that someone can help find this - blue lake with snowy mountain. I want to go here one day! Looks very serene. …

Q: [Where was this photo taken? (Windows 10 lock screen)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67684/where-was-this-photo-taken-windows-10-lock-screen)

Can someone point to a location, where this photograph was taken? It looks stunning! This is one of lockscreen wallpapers in Windows 10. …

Q: [Where was this photograph used as a Windows 10 wallpaper taken? [duplicate]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78254/where-was-this-photograph-used-as-a-windows-10-wallpaper-taken)

The photograph below is available as a wallpaper in Windows 10. Where was it taken? …

Q: [Where was this photo taken? Windows 10 photo lock screen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77284/where-was-this-photo-taken-windows-10-photo-lock-screen)

This photo popped upon my screen today, and I would actually really like to travel to this location one day. Does anyone know where it was taken?

Q: [Wallpaper picture location - Lake with mountains](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57161/wallpaper-picture-location-lake-with-mountains)

There is a Windows 10 lock screen wallpaper that really caught my attention. Does anyone know the location of this picture? Thank …

Q. [Would like to know where this picture was taken](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74378/would-like-to-know-where-this-picture-was-taken)

this picture showed up on the Windows Lock Screen and I would like to know where it was taken. I hope you can help me.

And in particular:

Q: [Is there a website listing the location of all the Windows 10 lock screens?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74404/is-there-a-website-listing-the-location-of-all-the-windows-10-lock-screens)

Windows 10 has an extensive collection of lock screen photos, many of which have prompted a question here on Travel.SE. Is there a website which lists the location of all of these photos? I imagine …

where @[JonathaReez](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/9009/jonathanreez)'s Answer includes:

> Windows 10 has added an update in the latest version allowing users to see where the photo came from.

Are any of the above candidates for a merger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

For the time being, Windows itself is providing information on the lock screen as to where the pictures are from. This was a recently added feature, and could be removed again. JonathonReez's Q/A would now, to my mind, be a good reason to close any new questions as dupes. However, the other answers all contain information that is not in [Is there a website listing the location of all the Windows 10 lock screens?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74404/is-there-a-website-listing-the-location-of-all-the-windows-10-lock-screens) - specifically, they contain information of where the picture in the first question was taken.